# avoiding screenshot duplication on market: 10" tablet, 7" tablet and phone screenshots all show with phone and laptop access,

Tags: android, screenshot

I added 10" and 7" screenshots as required for tablet optimization, but now I have duplicate screen shots of my two 10" tablet images, two 7" tablet images, first two phone images, all the same, that all show on the market.

when accessed from laptop or phone, the market first shows the two 10" tablet shots, then the two  7" tablet shots, then all the phone shots.

I used two of the the same screenshot images for all devices, pulled from each device separately (actually  an emulator for the tablets since I can't afford to buy tablets). since the screenshot window on the market goes through all the shots from all devices there is a lot of duplication.

I notice that other apps that optimized for tablets (they are on the tablet market app, mine doesn't show on it yet) don't have this issue (e.g. heroes call). their tablet screenshots don't appear at all for me, even when accessing from a laptop.

Should I attempt to contact support on this, it usually takes me weeks of trying to get a answer from support, which so for has just been a form letter response directing to go to a forum site (thus we end up providing our own support).

How can I keep my tablet screenshots from showing for those accessing from phone or laptop, thus avoiding duplication, particularly from showing first?